# How to fix Pyre undefined import error in my python project

Tags: python, github-actions, pyre-check

I'm using **Pyre action** from GitHub
but at the code scanning i got undefined import error

in my project I've already the requirement.txt

[Error on GitHub](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/67586090/192816584-1bce78c9-9027-4002-8657-9732560e980f.png), This is the error it shows

### This is the **requirements.txt**

```
auto-py-to-exe==2.23.1
customtkinter==4.6.3
Pillow==9.2.0
tk==0.1.0
```

Comment: Please share more info. Apparently this kind of issues are not uncommon (f.e. https://github.com/facebook/pyre-check/issues/278), but they highly depend on what tools are you using to manage your project (virtualenv, pipenv, conda etc.) and what is it's directory structure - where do you keep code, where the tests etc. and what is your pyre config.